# Materials available from crafting menu when shops restocked?

Tags: dust-an-elysian-tail

After some event in the game, you can craft items from your inventory. When having this ability and you start to craft something, you see the list of materials. When placing the cursor over the needed materiales you can access the shop to buy anything. That could be done everywhere.

Does this telepathic shop has the full catalog? Or there is any purpose to go to the physical shops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shop only has the materials that you sell to it. This 'Telepathic Shop' is the same as the ones you visit on the road. Every now and then a message will appear "Shop Restocked" meaning if they run out of something at some point, a small portion of the available materials have been restocked.

Comment: Yes, when I said "replenished" I meant "restocked". Didn't know the exact word in English since I have the game in my language

Comment: 'Replenished' and 'Restocked' mean the same thing :)